# Spawning NodeJS worker thread inside of async function doesn't respect promise resolution

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-worker-threads

I've got an async function that launches a NodeJS worker thread like so:

```
    encode : async (config) => {

      if (isMainThread) {

            const encode_worker = new Worker(`./service-encode.js`, { workerData: config });

            encode_worker.on('message', (transcode_data) => { 
              log.info("%o", transcode_data);
              return transcode_data;
            });

            encode_worker.on('error', (err) => { log.error(err)});
            encode_worker.on('exit', (code) => {
              if (code !== 0)
                throw new Error(`Encoding stopped with exit code [ ${code} ]`);
                console.log("* * * EXITED ENCODER WORKER * * *")

            });

      }

    },
```

In the `serivce-encode.js` file I've got the following code which uses async functions.  Note that I am using `postMessage` to signal that it is done.

```
var transcoder        = require('./transcoder');

const {Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData} = require('worker_threads');

console.log("* * * STARTING ENCODE THREAD * * *\n");
console.log(workerData);

transcoder.run(workerData)
          .then((results) => {
              transcode_data = results;
              parentPort.postMessage(transcode_data);
          })
          .catch(err => { throw err });
```

Then, I use the following example code but the code in the `'message'` event from above fires off immediately.  That is, it doesn't seem to wait until it's done:

```
encode(conf).then((encode_data) => { console.log("Encode Data :", encode_data);
```

The `encode` function works fine, but the `console.log` statement executes immediately when calling encode() function — also the `encode_data` var is `undefined`.  Since the `return` statement in the encode is in the `message` event, shouldn't the promise of the async function be resolved at that time?

Comment: Also, `.catch(err => { throw err });` in your worker thread doesn't really do anything useful does it?  Shouldn't you directly communicate back an error to the parent?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, absolutely — been doing a good deal of copy / paste.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, NOTHING about the code inside your `async` function supports promises.  You can't just throw random asynchronous (but not promise-based) code inside an `async` function and expect anything to work.  An `async` function will work just fine with promise-based asynchronous functions that you `await`.  Otherwise, it knows nothing about your asynchronous operations in there.  That's why calling `encode()` returns immediately without waiting for anything to complete.

In addition, `return transcode_data` is inside an asynchronous callback.  Returning inside that callback just goes back into the system code that called the callback and is dutifully ignored.  You're not returning anything there from the `async` function itself.  You're returning to that callback.

Since your operation is not promise-based, to solve this, you will have to make it promise-based by wrapping it in a promise and then manually resolved or rejecting that promise when needed with the proper values.  You can do that like this:

```
encode: (config) => {

    if (isMainThread) {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const encode_worker = new Worker(`./service-encode.js`, { workerData: config });

            encode_worker.on('message', (transcode_data) => {
                log.info("%o", transcode_data);
                resolve(transcode_data);
            });

            encode_worker.on('error', (err) => {
                log.error(err)
                reject(err);
            });

            encode_worker.on('exit', (code) => {
                if (code !== 0) {
                    reject(new Error(`Encoding stopped with exit code [ ${code} ]`));
                }
                console.log("* * * EXITED ENCODER WORKER * * *")
            });

        });


    } else {
        // should return a promise from all calling paths
        return Promise.reject(new Error("Can only call encode() from main thread"));
    }

},
```

FYI, this code assumes that the "result" you're looking for here from the promise is the `transcode_data` you get with the first `message` from this worker.

Comment: Many thanks for the lesson!  I had always thought that the `async / await` pattern was "syntactic sugar" for manually implementing the Promise with resolve / reject.  Is that not the case?  I will try your code and give it a shot.   Thank you for your time.

Comment: @ariestav - `async` allows you to use `await`.  It's not just syntactic sugar.  `await` enables much, much simpler coding in many circumstances.  But, `await` and thus `async` only does something useful when you're using it with operations that are already promise-based.  Yours were not so step #1 is to make them promise-based which, for a situation like this, has to be done manually.